# XSLT for-each question

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml

```
<Root>
  <Parent>
    <Child1>A</Child1>
    <Child2>B</Child2>
    <Child1>X</Child1>
    <Child2>Y</Child2>
  </Parent>
</Root>
```

Child2 always will be with child1. I need to know how I can loop through using `xsl:foreach` and create an XML output example.

```
<TransformedXML>
  <Child attribute1="A" attribute2="B"/>
  <Child attribute1="X" attribute2="Y"/>
</TransformedXML>
```

My question is how do I loop in XSLT considering Child2 node will follow a Child1 always?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short and efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowingChild1" match="*[not(self::Child1)]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Child1[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="Parent">
  <TransformedXML>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </TransformedXML>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Child1">
  <Child>
   <xsl:for-each select=".|key('kFollowingChild1', generate-id())">
    <xsl:attribute name="attribute{position()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </Child>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided (corrected many times to become well-formed!) XML document**:

```
<Root>
    <Parent>
        <Child1>A</Child1>
        <Child2>B</Child2>
        <Child1>X</Child1>
        <Child2>Y</Child2>
    </Parent>
</Root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<TransformedXML>
   <Child attribute1="A" attribute2="B"/>
   <Child attribute1="X" attribute2="Y"/>
</TransformedXML>
```

Comment: Thanks. Also What if myChild is 



<Root>
    <Parent>
        <Child1><Small>1</small></Child1>
        <Child2>B</Child2>
        <Child1>X</Child1>
        <Child2>Y</Child2>
    </Parent>
</Root>


How can I loop thru the Child1 to get small with the above XSLT. I am confused why I am getting the inner Text.

Comment: @Greens: I don't understand -- please, describe better. What do you want to get as result (XML, please)?

Comment: INPUT
<Root>  <Parent>  <Child1><Small>1</small></Child1>  <Child2>B</Child2>  <Child1>X</Child1>  <Child2>Y</Child2>  </Parent> </Root>
------------------------------------
OUTPUT
<TransformedXML>
   <Child attribute1="A" anyName="1" attribute2="B"/>
   <Child attribute1="X" attribute2="Y"/>
</TransformedXML>

Comment: This is significantly different than what you're asking in your question. Please, ask a new question with your new requirements. Think well before posting the new question, or you may miss something important again. For example, it is not clear in your new desired output, what `anyName` should mean and how it is related to the source XML.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you wan't to use `xsl:for-each`? I'd suggest to just use matching templates:

```
<xsl:template match="Child1">
  <Child attribute1="{.}" attribute2="{following-sibling::*[1]}"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Child2"/>
```

This will work just fine as long as the prerequisite that `Child1` always will be the first following sibling of `Child2`.